# Are Fusioncharts still maintained? Any alternative?

Tags: printing, fusioncharts, gantt-chart

Maybe Fusioncharts are the best for representing charts on web pages, but they fall when trying to embed them in documents. The Gantt chart, particularly, is somewhat poor in features.

It has been more than a year that I'm looking for some bug fix and new features, but no movement is heard from them.

Are Fusionchart still maintained or shall I look for something else?

If so, which are the best alternatives, expecially for printing and for useful Gantt charts?

Answer (score 0):

I want to be open from the beginning ;-) My answer is biased, as I am representing a vendor of Gantt software controls. I cannot comment on Fusioncharts, but am referring to your last sentence in which you ask for useful Gantt charts.

We are specialized on exactly this: Gantt chart software controls to be embedded in planning and scheduling applications. We do this for more than 30 years, and have built deep knowledge and domain expertise with respect to Gantt charts. Of course, we provide print functionality and a lot of standard options to customize the prints. Some of these functions are shown in the last part of this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oXRUy90lpsM).

Also, we have summarized 10 simple, but powerful features that developers should look for if they plan to write a Gantt-based scheduling application. Recently, we published them (incl. a short demo video) in our [Gantt Software Blog](http://blog.netronic.com/gantt-charts-10-simple-powerful-features).

I hope that this is helpful. What kind of project are you working on?

Comment: Thank you. I need a Gantt chart to display resources allocation and, maybe, change it. The chart has to be embedded in our web pages (so, when used to just display data, it must be possible to have only the chart, without buttons or other in-chart controls) as well as be included in server-side generated pdfs...

Comment: From what I read here, I would assume that we support this. Why not testing it, and we delivering a proof of concept? If you would share your requirements and sample data, we could create a rapid protoype for you.

Comment: We're going to study this problem in a few weeks. I'll have a look on your products and try to figure them in our software. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes Gantt Charts from FusionCharts desk have improved. Check [here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/usage-guide/gauge-and-widgets-guide/gantt-chart/introduction.html)